# Outline CSS Animation not working on Safari

Tags: css, safari

I am trying to set an animation on some of my buttons by adding a dedicated class. I have created an animation, which works in Chrome, but not in Safari (I'm using SCSS, so it's automatically prefixed for me).

When I try other properties (such as rotate), the animation actually works, but not with "outline". I also have tried to "separate" the properties (instead of the shorthanded version), to no avail.

```css
.comparable_data {
  animation: showComparableData 1s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes showComparableData {
  0% {
    outline: none;
  }
  65% {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    outline-offset: 1px;
  }
  75% {
    outline: 4px solid red;
    outline-offset: 4px;
  }
  100% {
    outline: 5px solid red;
    outline-offset: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="awesome comparable_data">Awesome</button>
```

```
<button class="awesome comparable_data">Awesome</button>

.comparable_data {
  animation: showComparableData 1s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes showComparableData {
  0% {
    outline: none;
  }
  65% {
    outline: 1px solid color(default);
    outline-offset: 1px;
  }
  75% {
    outline: 4px solid color(default);
    outline-offset: 4px;
  }
  100% {
    outline: 5px solid color(default);
    outline-offset: 5px;
  }
}
```

On Chrome, my button is "glowing" with the outline expanding back and forth from the button. On Safari, nothing is happening... and I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by specifying a starting state in the `comparable_data` class:

```css
.comparable_data {
  animation: showComparableData 1s linear infinite alternate;
  outline: 2px solid red;
}

@keyframes showComparableData {
  0% {
    outline: 0px solid red;
    outline-offset: 0px;
  }
  65% {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    outline-offset: 1px;
  }
  75% {
    outline: 4px solid red;
    outline-offset: 4px;
  }
  100% {
    outline: 5px solid red;
    outline-offset: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="awesome comparable_data">Awesome</button>
```

You might need to edit the values or add some margin, since it clips out of view sometimes.

I also added an `outline-offset` to the first keyframe - it's not strictly necessary, as far as I know, but can be useful to see.